# Meteor facebook does not fetch friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am logging in to my meteor app using facebook and i am getting my data and that of my friends like this

```
var user = Meteor.user();
   if (user.hasOwnProperty('services') && user.services.hasOwnProperty('facebook')  ) {
        var result = Meteor.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/' + user.services.facebook.id + '?access_token=' + user.services.facebook.accessToken + '&fields=first_name, last_name, birthday, email, gender, location, link, friends');

        console.log(result.data.first_name);
        console.log(result.data.last_name);
        console.log(result.data.birthday);
        console.log(result.data.email);
        console.log(result.data.gender);
        console.log(result.data.location);
        console.log(result.data.link);
        console.log(result.data.friends);
     }
```

The console logs gives my data as expected but when i come to this part

```
console.log(result.data.friends);
```

no the array seems to be empty although in the app permissions,i have allowed my friends to be listed. This is the entire response

```
2016-09-22T00:08:28.304409+00:00 app[web.1]: John
2016-09-22T00:08:28.304468+00:00 app[web.1]: Doe
2016-09-22T00:08:28.304939+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
2016-09-22T00:08:28.304969+00:00 app[web.1]: myemail@gmail.com
2016-09-22T00:08:28.305030+00:00 app[web.1]: male
2016-09-22T00:08:28.305145+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
2016-09-22T00:08:28.305241+00:00 app[web.1]: https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xx6741179689xxxxx/
2016-09-22T00:08:28.306279+00:00 app[web.1]: { data: [], summary: { total_count: 1 } }
```

In the facebook account i am using,i only have one friend,since the account is new and i only ever use it for testing so `total_count` of friends is 1.

What could i be doing wrong.

Comment: First of you are only allowed to have one account. Secondly you don't allow if friends can be listed. Your friends need to grant user_friends to your app for them to be listed

Comment: They have granted permissions to the app.

Comment: Both the access token that you are using and the friend that doesn't show up has granted user_friends permission to the app?

Comment: Good point. I am using facebook as a method to login the user,so i am guessing when the user is logging in he/she grants my app the permissions needed. I am friends with someone else using the app and i cant seem to list him/her. Strange.

Comment: Stop guessing, and _verify_ instead. Users don’t need to grant your app all the permissions it asks for, but they can selectively remove them.